# How does the minimal polynomial changes when a matrix is scaled?

Tags: linear-algebra, minimal-polynomials

if $A$ is a matrix of $n \times n$, that has a minimal polynomial of $P(t)$ of a degree of $k$, while $k<n$.
than the minimal polynomial of $cA$, $(c \neq 0)$ is:

1. $c^n P(\dfrac{t}{c})$
2. $c^kP(\dfrac{t}{c})$

or none of the above ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For any polynomial $Q$ we have $Q(A) = 0 \iff Q((cA)/c) = 0$. Because $P$ generates the ideal $\mathcal{I}_A = \{Q \in K[X] \mid Q(A) = 0\}$ it follows that $P(t/c)$ generates the ideal $\mathcal{I}_{cA} = \{Q \in K[X] \mid Q(cA) = 0\}$. Notice that the leading coefficient of $P(t/c)$ is $1/c^k$. Because the minimal polynomial is monic we have to take $c^k P(t/c)$.

Answer (score 2):

I think (2) is the right answer.  If $P(t)$ is the minimal polynomial of $A$,

$$P(A)=0\iff P((cA)/c)=0$$

Since $P(t)$ is degreee $k < n$, if we substitute $A'=cA$ into (2), the leading term of $P(t/c)$ will be $\frac{1}{c^k}A'^k$, that's why we need to multiply it by $c^k$ so that the minimal polynomial is monic.